# Захожу на localhost:8080, а там EDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Как освободить localhost:8080
Хочу запустить Spring приложуху пустую, а он выдает[image: Вот эту залупу]

Comment: Потушите приложение, которое слушает 8080(судя по всему это БД Постгри)

Answer (score 3):

Вам необходимо выполнить следующую последовательность шагов:

1. Перейдите в "выполнить", затем наберите "services.msc"
2. Найдите службу "PEM HTTPD" с описанием наподобие "Apache/2.4.39 (Win32)"
3. Правый клик по службе и нажать "Остановить"

[Оригинал вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026506/edb-postgres-server-from-local-host-apache-server-is-up-and-running-the-default)